# Java - Can I cast a variable modification from one class to another?

Tags: java

Say I have in class `A`:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

Now, say in class `B` I have a function:

```
public int void reset(String intName, A classA) {
...
}
```

Within `reset()` if I do `reset('c', classA)`, then I want `c` in `classA` to be reset. If I do a `reset('b', classA)`, then I want `b` in `classA` to be reset and so forth. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I need this to kill off units of different classes in a game.

Comment: This is possible with reflection, but most likely there is a better solution without using reflection.

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Setting it to 0?

Comment: why do u need to cast? just reset value of members of A in reset through A

Comment: While this might be possible with reflection, I think you rather should look over your code structure. You say you want to kill/reset certain units: how do you know which units to kill? Can you iterate over all units and store those with the "kill this" flag, maybe?

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah, just nulling it.

Comment: Without knowing more about your code, it's hard to make suggestions, but if you want to accomplish the above, you cold store your data in a `Map<String, Integer>` or even better `Map<Enum<?>, Integer>`. That way your implementation of reset would be `map.put("foo", 0)`.

Comment: are you variables really named as `a,b,c..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design my class A like this:

```
class A
{
   public enum UnitType { TANK, TRIKE, COMMANDO };

   public void reset (UnitType type); 

   //or even:
   public void reset (Set<UnitType> types); 

}
```

So class B could call:

```
a.reset(UnitType.TANK);
```

or in the `Set` case

```
a.reset(EnumSet.of(UnitType.TANK, UnitType.COMMANDO));
```

or

```
a.reset(EnumSet.allOf(UnitType.class));
```

You can still choose in `class A` how to keep track of the counts, without influencing the interface to `class B`

For example, class A can use a `Map` internally to keep track of the counts (which seems a good idea), but also fields, or any other method.

Comment: +1 This feels like a very elegant solution to this problem (assuming that `a`, `b`, and `c` do not in fact represent disparate types). Nice usage of `EnumSet.allOf` too (though having `A` abstract that with a `resetAll` type method could be useful too.

Comment: @nbrooks Thank you. I think the power of `Enum` & `EnumSet` should be in all Java tutorials, because it makes code more readable and reduces errors by enforcing the strict set of values. (and because you can use `==` for equality checks in enums)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through reflection. But since reflection is slow, I advise you not to try reflection immediately. Try something else first. Why can't you just do:

```
someObjectOfA.a = some value;
someObjectOfA.b = some value;
someObjectOfA.c = some value;
```

Anyway, here is the solution using reflection:

```
public static void reset(String name, A a) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<A> clazz = A.class;
    Field f = clazz.getField(name);
    f.set(a, 0);
}
```

Note that `a`, `b` and `c` must be declared `public` or a `NoSuchFieldException` will be thrown.

If you don't want to expose your fields, you can add setters like this one:

```
public void setA(Integer value) {
    a = value;
}
```

Then the `reset` method will be:

```
public static void reset(String name, A a) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<A> clazz = A.class;
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("set" + name.toUpperCase(), Integer.class);
    m.invoke(a, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options here, even without using reflection (i.e. dynamically modifying arbitrary properties of the object by names specified at runtime). The simplest is to simply have `A` be responsible for translating from the specified key to the corresponding variable:

```
public class A {
    private static int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

    public void reset(String key) {
        switch(key) {
        case "a": a = 0;
                  break;
        case "b": b = 0;
                  break;
        case "c": c = 0;
                  break;
        default:
                  break;
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    public int void reset(String intName, A obj) {
        obj.reset(intName);
    }
}
```

This leads to repetitive code though, and it's easy to make mistakes, especially as you add new fields to `A`.

---

A *better* option would be using a `Map` to dynamically map the property names to their values:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class A {
    private static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        map.put("A", 1);
        map.put("B", 2);
        map.put("C", 3);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getGameProperties() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public void reset(String key) {
        map.put(key, 0);
    }
}

public class B {
    public int void reset(String intName, A obj) {
        obj.reset(intName);
    }
}
```

This handles the property declaration and key mapping in a single step, so that fixes the issue of the repetitive, error-prone code. It does potentially affect the external interface of the class now since you got rid of the individual fields and replaced them with a `Map`. That's of course a good reason to keep your fields `private` and use getters/setters instead, since getters can be updated to look at a `Map` without changing the external API of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to have a something like setter in class A if you really want to reset it from other class?

Say I have in class A:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

public void resetA()
{
    this.a = 0;
}
public void resetB()
{
    this.b = 0;
}
public void resetC()
{
    this.c = 0;
}
```

or

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

public void resetAll()
{
    this.c = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 0;
}
```

i just can't think for now how to make a good coding for it's flexibility but it can reset you're value even from the other class if you like

Comment: The question is about how to set like this:  `void reset(String intName, A classA)`

Comment: Could do that but then with each new added unit you'd have to add a new getter, setter and if statement in the kill function.

Comment: @dit yes it is the question but we can also help by suggesting other solution but also close to what he wants to have :)

Comment: @Synlar. i just have a question. do you really want to reset it from different class like B class or C class? or can be reset from A class itself? because i am thinking of something that can be reset through different class through object passing

Answer (score 0):

Try this. No need to write setter method for each field.

```
        try
        {
            Field field = classA.getClass().getDeclaredField(intName);    
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(classA);
            System.out.println(" val "+ value);
            field.set(classA, 0);//Reset to zero
            value = field.get(classA);
            System.out.println(" val "+ value);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```